# BIRT text data instances return null text in render event

Tags: birt

I've a simple BIRT report design file containing a grid and a cell with:

```
<text-data>
  <expression name="valueExpr">params["sample"]</expression>
  <property name="contentType">plain</property>
</text-data>
```

In beforeRender design phase, I've attached an eventHandlerClass to the corresponding TextDataHandle.
In the DynamicTextEventAdapter#onRender event handler, I'm printing the getText() value of the IDynamicTextInstance(which corresponds to the text-data above) but the text is always null.
However, in the DynamicTextEventAdapter#onPageBreak, the value is printed correctly.

Any idea what could cause this to happen?
For other elements like DataItemS, I can correctly retrieve the value in #onRender.

Comment: not quite sure if the value should be available on that stage, it sounds like you're mixing two elements? Take a look at: http://www.eclipse.org/birt/documentation/integrating/scripting.php

Comment: not sure what to look for in there(can't see anything DynamicText related), but do you know at which stage I'd be able to access the value in DynamicText? I've seen DynamicText implementation has a ForeignContent and a DataItem. The foreign content has the value but the DataItem is populated much later, in the PageBreak event